# Directx9 and Windows UAC Problem. How can I fix ground distortion?

Tags: windows, textures, directx, alpha, uac

In order to improve myself, I work on ready-made resources. However, I am currently faced with a problem that has been bothering me for days. When I first open the game, everything works fine, but when the Windows User Control (UAC) screen comes up through any program, the background visuals in my game are distorted. I am very novice in these matters, I would be very happy if you could help me in a way that I can understand.
Thank you very much

Original:

[image]

After UAC:

[image]

First code:

```
    if (FAILED(hr = ms_lpd3dDevice->TestCooperativeLevel()))
    {
      if (D3DERR_DEVICELOST == hr)
         return DEVICESTATE_BROKEN;

      if (D3DERR_DEVICENOTRESET == hr)
         return DEVICESTATE_NEEDS_RESET;

     return DEVICESTATE_BROKEN;
    }
```

Then this place is triggered:

```
case CGraphicDevice::DEVICESTATE_NEEDS_RESET:

   m_pyBackground.ReleaseCharacterShadowTexture();
   CRenderTargetManager::Instance().ReleaseRenderTargetTextures();

   Trace("DEVICESTATE_NEEDS_RESET - attempting");
   if (!m_grpDevice.Reset())
   {
       return DEVICE_STATE_SKIP;
   }

   CRenderTargetManager::Instance().CreateRenderTargetTextures();
   m_pyBackground.CreateCharacterShadowTexture();

   break;
```

Comment: The code you show doesn't help, every detal is important for that type of question, it's difficult to say w/o a small reproducible project https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier As a result of my analysis, I could only reach these two code blocks. Since I have no knowledge of Directx programming, SetVertexShader, etc. I don't know where I should use basic concepts such as. However, the problem only occurs during UAC. I think I need to reprocess the textures after UAC, but I haven't been able to do that yet. I hope there is a way to achieve this in the second code I showed. I would appreciate it if you could give an example.

Comment: If you have no specific reason to use DirectX9, you should use DirectX11 or 12 then (not that it will change anything to your problem though)

Comment: Most likely you are forgetting to see all the render state you rely on each frame. It's not generally robust to rely on the device to stay in a particular state from frame-to-frame, although in legacy Direct3D 9 this "kind of" works. In modern DirectX 12, this is absolutely not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the screenshots, it seems after the lost device and desktop switch, Windows resets sampler state you use to load from your low-resolution texture from linear to the default which is `D3DTEXF_POINT`.

You should restore the state by calling `IDirect3DDevice9.SetSamplerState` method the same way you do on startup of your app.

P.S. Direct3D 11 is much better than 9 in that regard, most of the times it manages these states automagically.